# How to use bootstrap toggle buttons in angular application for on and off

Tags: bootstrap-4, toggle, angular-ui-bootstrap, togglebutton, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I want to use the bootstrap toggle buttons(switch buttons) in angular.(The components has to come dynamically from the backend ).

I have tried but toggling the switches is not working properly.

**.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor ="let sensor of sensors;let i =index"  (ngModelChange)="dataChanged(selectsensor)" >
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (click)="dataChanged(sensor,i)" id="customSwitches">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">
    {{sensor.name}}  </label>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell us what you are trying to do in the function call **dataChanged()** And you are calling the same function with different parameter.

From this structure

```
<input type="checkbox" 
class="custom-control-input" 
(click)="dataChanged(sensor,i)" id="customSwitches">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">
{{sensor.name}}  </label>
```

to

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  class="custom-control-input"
  id="customSwitches{{i}}"
/>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches{{i}}">
{{sensor.name}}  </label>
```

The id of the element is duplicated **n number(n - number of sensors)** of times in your structure. As per standard we can't duplicate the same id. So please index of the sensor to it. now it's working for me.

Note: we don't know what is the implementation inside the function **dataChanged()**. That also might cause issue. We removed both the function call from both places.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me one more last requirement is that I want to activate first toggle button can you please help me

Comment: @Haritha, you can do it through attr.checked. Like below. Instead of the status variable you can have your own dynamic variable. 

<input
      type="checkbox"
      class="custom-control-input"
      id="customSwitches{{i}}"
      [attr.checked]="sensor.status===true?true:null"
    />

if shared answer helps you upvote it. Thanks.